# Getting an error message when triggering plugin load with vim-plug

Tags: plugin-system, error, plugin-vim-plug

I'm new to the world of plugins, and have just installed vim-plug (well, sort of). My `.vimrc` has:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline', { 'on':  'Airline' }
call plug#end()
```

... since I don't want the plugin to always be used. Now, if I use the `:Airline` command, the plugin does start, but before it does, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>10_lod_cmd:
line    3:
E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command: Airline
```

I also see this happening if I add and toggle a different plugin, e.g. NERDTree.

Note: I'm using a somewhat old version of Vim,  on a SLES15 machine:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12)
Included patches: 1-1568
```

Comment: There is no `:Airline` command. There are several commands that start with `:Airline` however.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to put a valid airline command for the 'on' option like:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline', { 'on':  'AirlineToggle' }
call plug#end()
```